# LINQ Order by Error

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have a Custom Collection:

```
public class CustomCollection: ObservableCollection<MyViewModel>
{
    private String _sPError = String.Empty;
    public String SPError
    {
        get { return _sPError; }
        set { _sPError = value; }
    }
}
```

Now I Have a Property :

```
public CustomCollection MyCollecionObject
{
}

//Working Fine    
 MyCollecionObject = GetValueFromCollection();// Return Type is CustomCollection
```

This works fine but if I want to sort using:

```
//Not Working , Getting the Error
    MyCollecionObject = (GetValueFromCollection()).OrderByDescending(x=>x.StartTime);
```

I get the following exception:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable' to CustomCollection'.

How Can I  Orderby 'CustomCollection ' using start date inside MyViwModel

Comment: And the question is... ?

Comment: @zerkms How do I get rid of the error and able to Orderby 'CustomCollection ' using start date   inside MyViwModel

Comment: you haven't provided a signature for `GetValueFromCollection`. Do we need to guess it?

Comment: @zerkms obviously how to make this work... only because there´s no questionmark within the Post it does not mean its not a valid SO-question.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: I did not say it's not valid, I just pointed out that OP did not ask anything.

Comment: @zerkms, Return Type is CustomCollection

Comment: That's what it is trying to do When I am trying to do OrderBy . But as I said CollecionObject = GetValueFromCollection(); is working fine .

Answer (score 2):

`CustomCollection` is an `ObservableCollection<T>` and the result of `OrderByDescending` is an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` which aren't compatible.

`ObservableCollection<T>` has a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679169(v=vs.110).aspx) that allows you to pass in an `IEnumerable<T>` as the source so you could do something like

```
var orderedCollection = GetValueFromCollection().OrderByDescending(x => x.StartTime);
MyCollectionObject = new CustomCollection(orderedCollection.AsEnumerable());
```

Answer (score 1):

The right hand side of your assignment is not of type CustomCollection. You need to construct a CustomCollection from the IOrderedEnumerable returned by your LINQ statement.